# How can I make a SVG crop as page is shrinked (resized) instead of resizing the svg itself

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

My goal is to make my SVG act the same way as [Netlify](https://netlify.com)'s SVG.

**SVG Code**

```
<svg min-width="1152" min-height="523" viewBox="0 0 1152 523" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M592 383C457.295 487.224 134.333 527 0 522V0H1154V172C1001.67 191 729 277 592 383Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="577" y1="0" x2="577" y2="522.669" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="#04724D"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#23E8A5"/>
    </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

**Html Code**

```
<div class="home_background">
    <a class="btn btn-white btn-right">Sign Up</a>
</div>
```

I am also using *gatsby.js*, although it doesn't affect the end result.

Comment: Not very sure I understand what you are asking. Please try this: `<svg viewBox="0 0 1152 523" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"  fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">`

Comment: @enxaneta My goal is to make the svg crop as the page is resized instead of resizing in the pages width.

Comment: remove the viewBox attribute.